# how to compare two dictionaries in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two dictionaries; dict and dictdisc. The key in dict looks like `(numbers)-(discipline code)-(numbers)` while the key in dictdisc just has `(discipline code)`. I tried using the code below but it doesn't work because `dict.Exists` sees  `"*" & discode & "*"` as a literal string of `"*EL*"` instead of `"(anything)EL(anything)"` which would result in a `True` outcome. - EL here is a discipline code for Electrical.

I am at a loss at the moment. Would really appreciate if someone could lend a helping hand :)

```
For Each dictkey In dict.Keys
      Set oEntry = dict(dictkey)
      ' Check to see if discipline code exists in the discipline dictionary
      For Each discode In dictdisc.Keys
            If dict.Exists("*" & discode & "*") Then
                Set srchrng = MainWS.Range("B:B")
                DiscRowMain = Application.Match("*" & dictdisc.Item(key) & "*", srchrng, 0)
                    If IsError(DiscRowMain) Then
                        MsgBox ("Discipline Not Found")
                    End If
                    ' Write out the values
                    With oEntry
                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 1).Value = key
                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 2).Value = .Info
                    ....
                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 19).Value = .tpCost
                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 20).Value = .rmk
                    row = row + 1
                    End With
            End If
      Next discode
Next dictkey
```

[image: This is how individual file submission from each discipline should look like (keep it mind they might also put in entries in other discipline table)]

[image: This is what the master file should look like, after compiling everything]

Comment: Need more info. 1. Are there any digits **within** the discipline code? 2. Might you have multiple entries in `dict` for the same discipline code? 3. Are you retrieving the entries from `dict` or from `dictDisc` when there is a match?

Comment: To answer your question. 1. There are no digits within the discipline code. 2. Yes, there could certainly be multiple entries for the same discipline code. For example, Process could submit a file that has 001-PR-001, 001-PR-002, etc. as entries. They sometimes would also submit an entry that has other discipline codes (such as 001-GN-003) which needs to be sorted in the master file. 3. The entries are from dict. dict is what I use to loop through all the files and store the entries whereas dictDisc is only a file that has discipline code as its key and the discipline itself as its item.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not give an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I made something up which means I could totally be wrong.

I took your code, commented the in my opinion irrelevant part and reduced it to that

```
Sub test()

Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dictkey As Variant
Dim oEntry

Dim discode As Variant
Dim dictdisc As New Scripting.Dictionary

dict.Add "10-EL-100", "1"
dict.Add "2-AB-10", 2

dictdisc.Add "EL", "Electric"
dictdisc.Add "AR", "Archiv"


For Each dictkey In dict.Keys
      'Set oEntry = dict(dictkey)
      ' Check to see if discipline code exists in the discipline dictionary
      For Each discode In dictdisc.Keys
            
            'If dict.Exists("*" & discode & "*") Then
            If myExist(CStr(discode), dict) Then
'            If dict.Exists("10-" & discode & "-100") Then
                Debug.Print "Exist"
'                Set srchrng = MainWS.Range("B:B")
'                DiscRowMain = Application.Match("*" & dictdisc.Item(Key) & "*", srchrng, 0)
'                    If IsError(DiscRowMain) Then
'                        MsgBox ("Discipline Not Found")
'                    End If
'                    ' Write out the values
'                    With oEntry
'                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 1).Value = Key
'                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 2).Value = .Info
'                    ....
'                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 19).Value = .tpCost
'                    MainWS.Cells(DiscRowMain + 2, 20).Value = .rmk
'                    Row = Row + 1
'                    End With
            End If
      Next discode
Next dictkey

End Sub
```

As you see I replaced your if condition  `If dict.Exists("*" & discode & "*") Then` with `If myExist(CStr(discode), dict) Then` and used the following function

```
Function myExist(inKey As String, dict As Scripting.Dictionary) As Boolean

    Dim vKey As Variant
    
    For Each vKey In dict.Keys
        If vKey Like "*" & inKey & "*" Then
            myExist = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    
    Next vKey

End Function
```

If this does not help please be more specific and give as mentioned an MVCE.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you are stuck on being able to access each entry in `dict` given a particular discipline.

One way to solve that issue is to create a third dictionary where the key is the discipline, and the item stored is a collection of all the `dict` entries for that discipline. We remove the digits from the `dict` keys to use them.

Once you have that, you can iterate through the collection contained in this new dictionary, using the `dictDisc` keys, in order to access the `dict` keys for the corresponding discipline.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub compareSimilarDictionaries()
    Dim dict As Dictionary, dictDisc As Dictionary, dictCombined As Dictionary
    Dim v, w, x, y, s As String, col As Collection
    
'setup the example
Set dict = New Dictionary
    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
Set dictDisc = New Dictionary
    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
v = Array("123EL123", "124PB124", "125HDW125", "001EL002")

For Each w In v
    Select Case remNums(w)
        Case "EL"
            s = "electric"
        Case "PB"
            s = "plumbing"
        Case "HDW"
            s = "hardware"
        Case Else
            s = ""
    End Select
    dict.Add w, w
        If Not dictDisc.Exists(remNums(w)) Then _
    dictDisc.Add remNums(w), s
Next w

'show the keys
v = dict.Keys
Debug.Print "dict"
For Each w In v
    Debug.Print w, dict(w)
Next w
Debug.Print

Debug.Print "dictDisc"
v = dictDisc.Keys
For Each w In v
    Debug.Print w, dictDisc(w)
Next w

'are they are like each other
'set up combined dictionary
'comparison dictionary will have discipline as the key, and a collection of all the corresponding dict entries.
Set dictCombined = New Dictionary
    dictCombined.CompareMode = TextCompare

v = dict.Keys
For Each w In v
    s = remNums(w) 'generate the lookup key
    
    'optional test to ensure the discipline actually exists in dictDisc before adding to dictCombined
    If Not dictDisc.Exists(s) Then
        MsgBox "The discipline " & s & " does not exist." & vbLf & "What do you want to do?"
        'go fix this
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not dictCombined.Exists(s) Then
        Set col = New Collection
        col.Add w
        dictCombined.Add Key:=s, Item:=col
    Else
        dictCombined(s).Add w
    End If
Next w

'Now you can go through dictCombined to find all the matching dict entries
'eg
For Each v In dictDisc.Keys
    For Each w In dictCombined(v) 'w will be the collection of dict entries
        With dict(w)
            'do whatever
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "dict entries" & vbTab & dict(w)
        End With
    Next w
Next v
    
End Sub

Function remNums(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim I As Long
    For I = 0 To 9
        s = Replace(s, I, "")
    Next I
remNums = s
End Function
```

Comment: I really appreciate you spending your time to reply. Thank you so much. 
1. For your first For Each, if I'm not mistaken, you're adding onto discDict disciplines that are not available on there depending on the entry key? If so, I've already added all the discipline codes along with the corresponding discipline name in discDict as Strings. Also, won't using remNums just remove the numbers from the entry key? If so, what would be left would look something like -EL- or in some cases -ST-J-.

Comment: 2. Aside from that, I avoided using the dict entries as items because for each `dict` entries, the `key` would be the entry key (numbers&discipline code&numbers) and the `item` is a class that I made.
I edited my post to show how the table looks like and if you can see it from there, each entry has multiple columns populated. I combined all the columns into a class and used the left most column as the entry key. This way, I can work out which discipline each entry corresponds to and then insert each row into its respective discipline table in the master file.

Comment: The first loops are merely to set up dictionaries to show the concept. For `dict`, it doesn't matter what is stored in it for testing -- class, string whatever.  I understood your problem to be that you wanted to use the discipline key -- eg `EL` to look up an entry in `dict`. This will enable you do to it by using `EL` as the key to `dictCombined` which will contain all of the matching keys in `dict`. You then use the contents of the `dictCombined` entry as keys to retrieve the entries from `dict`

Comment: So far as removing the digits, that was how I understood your keys to be constructed. (digits)(disciplineCode)(digits) from what you wrote.  If removing the digits doesn't do that, you just need to write a function that extracts the discipline code from your `dict` keys.